# Dynamically adding views each row of listview

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have a nested array to display in my Listview.Each row of the ListView will have a horizontal LinerLayout into HorizontalScrollView.

Currently I'm using ViewHolder pattern and dynamically adding views to the LinerLayout in the getView method of ListView.

The **Problem** is the listview lags when I scrolling..

This is my custom adapter class

```
public class ChannelArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Kanal> {
Context context;
List<Kanal> list;
List<Program> pList;
LayoutInflater inflator;

public ChannelArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Kanal> lis) {
    super(context, R.layout.channels, lis);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.list = lis;
    this.context = context;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    LinearLayout l;
}

static class ProgramHolder {
    TextView programAdi;
    TextView programSaati;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.channels, parent, false);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        viewHolder.l = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yayinAkisiLayout);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        viewHolder.l.removeAllViews();
    }

    final Kanal kanal = list.get(position);
    pList = kanal.getKanalProgramListesi();
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(kanal.getResourcesIkonKanal());

    for (Program p : pList) {
        View v = new View(context);
        v.setId(position);
        ProgramHolder pHolder = new ProgramHolder();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.programs, null);          
        pHolder.programSaati = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.psaati);
        pHolder.programAdi = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pname);
        pHolder.programAdi.setText(p.getProgramAdi());
        pHolder.programSaati.setText(p.getProgramBaslangic());
        v.setTag(pHolder);
        viewHolder.l.addView(v);
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: I tired your code for one of my implementation and it worked perfectly. didnt see much lag though.

Answer (score 0):

Make holder a static class and just edit its fields in getView. Your list view lags because you are creating few new objects each time getView is called -> each time new item is loaded or gaining visibility on your ListView.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

This explains everything in details how to make effective adapter/listView.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize this piece of code :

```
ProgramHolder pHolder = new ProgramHolder();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.programs, null);          
        pHolder.programSaati = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.psaati);
        pHolder.programAdi = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pname);
        pHolder.programAdi.setText(p.getProgramAdi());
        pHolder.programSaati.setText(p.getProgramBaslangic());
        v.setTag(pHolder);
        viewHolder.l.addView(v);
```

As `View Holder` pattern, you should store those layout, maybe in static variable too :

```
static  ProgramHolder pHolder;

if (pHolder == null) {
    View v = new View(context);
    v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.programs, null);          
    pHolder.programSaati = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.psaati);
    pHolder.programAdi = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pname);
}
```

The main purpose here is decrease times use `findViewById()`. after that, in loop, you can create custom view, and assign each fields base on `pHolder`.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you for answer.. I have tried but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: can you tell me size of plist ?

Comment: There is dynamically putting in array from json response but List<Kanal> list count is 25 and every each Kanal node has a 20-30 Program entity.